# Django : How to add/remove/update translation phrases (in po files) in django admin area?

Tags: python, django

How can we manage translation phrases stored in local\fa\LC_MESSAGES\django.po files by Django Admin area ?

I am looking for a package which able to update and compile django translation files like updating models in django Admin area

I am using Django 1.10

#### edited for Mohsen's replay

I am exactly looking for package like this :
[this image in designed in photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Api.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every content that exists in `*.po` files is not directly related to models, for example if you sets `verbose_name` of model field by django ugettext this content exist on the `*.po` file, but other thins such as template `trans` tag content also exist on these files.
You can use models translation apps such as [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) to translate models on the admin but you cant translations that not used directly definitioned on the models fields.

Comment: thanks mohsen, this is not what i am looking for. i am looking for django translation online editor in django admin panel

Comment: Ok, but translation must compile after change and django server reload to new translations applied. by this reasons i think you cant find any django app that made for this aim.

Comment: thanks mohsen, for one of my project i designed a django middle-ware to do that, but it seems there is no django package for this problem